# How do I embed an external website Into my website?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to embed external websites into my website so I can reference a website and have it show the website. I have tried doing this using this code:

`<iframe src="<WEBSITE URL>" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>`

This works for some websites like [www.wikipedia.org](https://www.wikipedia.org) but when I try other websites like [www.twitter.com](https://www.twitter.com) I just get an error message that says: "*twitter.com refused to connect.*" What can I do to get these other websites to be embedded into my website?

Comment: I think twitter blocked iframes or your browser blocks it because something like the same origin policy.

Comment: Is there an error in the devtools?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A website owner has the option to not allow it to be embeded in other sites. They can do this by using the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header. There is nothing you can do on your end to bypass this.

Running the curl command `curl -I https://twitter.com` you can see the list of headers and `x-frame-options: DENY` is one of them.

```
... snipped
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-response-time: 19
x-transaction: 00fafa890079c168
x-twitter-response-tags: BouncerCompliant
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection: 0
```